# Style host element on Stencil component based on class

Tags: css, web-component, stenciljs

In Stencil when you have set `shadow: true`, styling the host element is as follows

```
:host {
    color: red;
}
```

This works. But now I have the following component

```
@Component({
    tag: 'my-component',
    styleUrl: 'my-component.scss',
    shadow: true
})
export class MyComponent {
    @Element() host: HTMLElement;

    render() {
        this.host.classList.add('is-test');
        return <div>Test</div>;
    }
}
```

in which I add the `is-test` class to the host element. Now, to apply styling based on that class I added the following

```
:host {
    color: red;

    &.is-test {
        background-color: green;
    }
}
```

I see `is-test` class on `my-component` element, but the `background-color: green` style is not applied. I must be doing something wrong here, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [`:host()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:host()):

```css
:host {
    color: red;
}

:host(.is-test) {
    background-color: green;
}
```

By the way: If you want to set the class (or any attribute) on the host element, you can use [the `<Host>` functional component](https://stenciljs.com/docs/host-element):

```
import { Host } from '@stencil/core';

// ...

render() {
    return <Host class="is-test"><div>Test</div></Host>;
}
```

Comment: Nice! Isn't SCSS supposed to be able to use `:host { &.className{...} }`? I see it compileing to `:host.className {...` but styles not applying. Your solutions works though.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately that doesn't compile correctly and most likely won't be added because "[nesting is] only intended for simple use cases", see https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/3099